# CSS and filename coding conventions

Tags: css, naming-conventions, coding-style

What kind of convention do you (or your company) run on filenames and CSS class names? For example, let's say you have these class names: window, window top, window top left, window top right. How do you name those class names (and such filenames)?

Currently I am doing the following:

```
.window {
 background: url(images/window.png);
}

.window-top {
 background: url(images/window-top.png);
}

.window-top-left {
 background: url(images/window-top-left.png);
}
```

What other ways are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the class names, I assume this is CSS for some sort of widget or plugin.  The names you have given are pretty clear but to help avoid clashes I'd probably prefix them with a short plugin/widget specific string ie:

```
.mywindow-window{
}

.mywindow-window-top{
}

.mywindow-window-top-left{
}
```

These names are a little verbose, but should help make things clearer in the long run.

If I'm mistaken, then the naming convention you are hinting at should be fine - whats most important is that you are consistent.